# How to configure VS Code on Windows to run a task in WSL?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code 1.6 on Windows and have configured the integrated terminal to be bash:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
```

I want to build my C++ project using **make** running in WSL. So I defined a task:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [""],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

How can I configure that task to run in WSL?

How can I set the directory in which make should run? (not the root directory of the folder opened in Code, but a subfolder of it).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replacing  as appropriate:

`{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "c:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-c 'cd /mnt/c/<path>; make'"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}`

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion and it is not working yet. The command path seems wrong: `C:\>c:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.` I also tried `"command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"` but that gave `'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Can you help me with this please?